# Issue with int++ and page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, int

I am wondering why when I declare a public Int that I implement everytime I reload the page, the int is always going to 1.

This is the code I use.

I declare the int before the page load. And every page load the int is 1. It should be 2, 3 etc ...

```
    public int countIdPrevious;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       countIdPrevious++;

    }
```

Comment: You have to learn about the stateless nature of http. Your Page class is newly instantiated on each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because fields are not included in ViewState.

Turn this field into a [ViewState-backed property](http://www.codingwith.net/2008/01/viewstate-backed-properties-part-one.html) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is for each page load you get a new instance of your page class. In order to get around this you need to persist your variable in some other medium such as a session or the ViewState.